# Как найти путь максимальной стоимости в графе?

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дерево, динамическое-программирование

> Задано `N` вершин. Для каждой пары вершин заданы функции `d(n_i,n_j)` - расстояние и `c(n_i,n_j)` - стоимость.
>
> Можно соединять те пары вершин `i` и `j`, для которых `d(n_i,n_j) < F`, где `F` - фиксированное число. Начиная с вершины `n_0`, требуется построить путь **максимальной** стоимости.
>
> Нельзя провести путь дважды через одну и ту же вершину. Граф направленный.

Каков алгоритм?

Comment: 1) Построить матрицу смежности 2) Проверить на цикличность (если цикличен - любой бесконечный цикл является ответом) 3) Построить любым методом все пути выбрать самый дорогой.

Comment: @Akina да разные. Исправил

Comment: @Akina то что вы написали, понятно. Но как построить пути? Перебором долго

Comment: @Leeloo Путей экспоненциальное количество, так что ничего не поделаешь - например, выполняйте DFS или BFS, снимая пометку при возврате из рекурсии

Comment: @MBo Можете добавить подробное описаные в ответ?

Comment: *Начиная с вершины n_0, требуется построить путь максимальной стоимости.* То есть начальная вершина - фиксирована? и нужно найти путь (и соотв. конечную вершину) такой, что его стоимость максимальна среди всех путей? Тогда сразу возникает вопрос. Согласно описанию, граф ненаправленный, но тогда существует бесконечное множество бесконечных путей (X-A-B-A-B-A-...), и задача как бы бессмысленна. То есть для того, чтобы задача имела конечное множество решений (возможно, единственное), граф должен быть направленным и ациклическим.

Comment: @Akina я написал что нельзя пройти через одну и ту же вершину дважды

Comment: Судя по последнему исправлению - пути нужны простые? Тогда http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=56734 для поиска всех путей между парами вершин (в вашем случае destination не определён)

Comment: Ну тогда поиск в ширину или глубину (с пометкой/исключением посещённых вершин и, соответственно, их рёбер) - по вкусу... но в любом случае сперва строите матрицу связности. Ибо *Начиная с вершины n_0*, т.е. начальная вершина задана.

Comment: @MBo да, добавил еще условие направленности, чтобы сузить поиск решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для нахождения пути максимальной стоимости из заданной вершины придётся построить все простые (не пересекающие себя же по вершинам) пути из неё. Количество этих путей экспоненциально.  Для построения можно использовать модифицированный DFS или BFS, только пометка о том, что вершина уже использована в пути, должна быть локальной для данной ветви рекурсии.

Псевдокод, использующий глобальный список пометок вершин (в вашем случае Src постоянен, Destination не определён) - в этом случае пометка должна сниматься при возврате из рекурсии

```
VertexUsed: array[N] of Boolean;// инициализируется False
Route: список или строка

procedure FindRoute(V: Vertex)
if V =  Destination then
  Print(Route)
else
  для всех смежных с V вершин (W)
    if not VertexUsed[W] then begin
        VertexUsed[W] = True
        добавить W к Route
        FindRoute(W)
        VertexUsed[W] = False
        исключить W из Route
      end
```

Delphi код для поиска путей между двумя конкретными вершинами, использующий локальный параметр `Used`, биты которого содержат пометки для данной ветви

```
var
  Adj: array of array of Byte;
  Src, Dest: Integer;

  procedure FindRoute(V: Integer; Used: Integer; Route: string);
  var
    i, W: Integer;
  begin
    if V = Dest then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Route)
    else
      for i := 0 to High(Adj[V]) do begin
        W := Adj[V, i];
        if (Used and (1 shl W)) = 0 then
          FindRoute(W, Used or (1 shl W), Route + IntToStr(W) + ' ');
      end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(Adj, 7);
  SetLength(Adj[0], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[1], 2);
  SetLength(Adj[2], 2);
  SetLength(Adj[3], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[4], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[5], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[6], 2);
  Adj[0, 0] := 1;
  Adj[1, 0] := 0;
  Adj[0, 1] := 2;
  Adj[2, 0] := 0;
  Adj[0, 2] := 4;
  Adj[4, 0] := 0;
  Adj[1, 1] := 3;
  Adj[3, 0] := 1;
  Adj[2, 1] := 5;
  Adj[5, 0] := 2;
  Adj[3, 1] := 4;
  Adj[4, 1] := 3;
  Adj[3, 2] := 6;
  Adj[6, 0] := 3;
  Adj[4, 2] := 5;
  Adj[5, 1] := 4;
  Adj[5, 2] := 6;
  Adj[6, 1] := 5;
  Src := 0;
  Dest := 3;
  FindRoute(Src, 1 shl Src, IntToStr(Src) + ' ');
end;

выдача
0 1 3 
0 2 5 4 3 
0 2 5 6 3 
0 4 3 
0 4 5 6 3
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы заменить код на Delphi на описание предполагаемого алгоритма?

Comment: Как я уже написал, это поиск в ширину, пометка вершины в котором действует только в нижележащей ветви рекурсии

Comment: Что насчет алгоритма Беллмана-Форда?

Comment: Он предназначен для поиска кратчайших путей. Задача  же поиска максимального пути - NP-hard (кроме DAG)